# Need Quartis II CPLD tutorial for learning VHDL from ZERO

Tags: fpga, vhdl, programmable-logic, intel-fpga, quartus-ii

I am learning VHDL from zero using Altera CPLD. Already got Quartis II 12.1 and a 15-lines example VHDL (like Hello World for C learner).

To avoid learning bad coding style or digging too deep too early, what should I look out for?

Comment: @TonyEnnis Suggesting users google something is against site policy. LMGTFY is clearly throwing it in a users face that they clearly did not know how to google. Using a URL shortener to post it around the block is not okay. Such actions, if repeated, will result in suspension.

Comment: The way the site is designed to work is to answer precise technical questions. Ideally you would never ask where to find good references for learning something, you instead ask your questions here to gain insight and any question someone might have slowly accumulates here. Long term, the answer to any reading references would be: EE.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://hamsterworks.co.nz/mediawiki/index.php/FPGA_course) has a (PDF) book that is quite good on the process of learning the tools and the stages between VHDL and a working design. It uses the Xilinx tools and an FPGA but the steps are similar for Altera.

Plus it costs nothing except disk and bandwidth to download the Xilinx tools and have them on hand for comparison.

In particular he says quite a lot that I skipped over, on the process of diagnosing and optimising performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

DONE. Thanks for help.

Below and http://hamsterworks.co.nz/mediawiki/index.php/FPGA_course should be fine for the Hello World phase of learning.

Dated May 2012, Introduction Using VHDL Designs for Quartus II Version 12 
http://www.altera.com/education/univ/software/quartus2/unv-quartus2.html